# Is quesion about Caliphet is too localized?

Tags: discussion

for example this question is closed with the said reason of being too localized.

https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/612/what-is-caliph-according-to-quran/691#691

local means related to a geographical location.

I do not see any relation to a specific relation in this question.

so I am confused why this question is "too localized"?

it is not localized at all to be too localized.

Caliphate is a subject of leadership of Islamic Ummah. today we have Ummah and the subject of leadership is an alive subject today.

it is not related to 1400 years ago only.

I think some moderators are not qualified to decide about localization of Islamic subjects and so they close questions falsely due to their lack of knowledge about some Islamic topics.

Answer (score 2):

That question was closed  because of the following line:

> Please reply only from the Quran and with a word having the root of Caliph in it.

Questions and answers on the Stack Exchange network are generally expected to be useful to future visitors; by specifying such a *precise* criteria for answers, especially for a subject as potentially complex as etymology, this question is unlikely to be of any future use.

As the close text states (emphasis mine),

> **This question is unlikely to help any future visitors**; it is only
>   relevant to a small geographic area, a specific moment in time, or **an
>   extraordinarily narrow situation** that is not generally applicable to
>   the worldwide audience of the internet. For help making this question
>   more broadly applicable, [see the FAQ](https://islam.stackexchange.com/faq#close).